# What can I do when neo4j sends an UnderlyingStorageException?

Tags: java, glassfish, neo4j, nio

I just encountered it and am totally flabergasted :

```
[#|2012-12-10T14:16:49.663+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jtsxa|_ThreadID=165;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5068: Unexpected error occurred in rollback
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to write defragged id  batch
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.IdGeneratorImpl.writeIdBatch(IdGeneratorImpl.java:554)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.IdGeneratorImpl.freeId(IdGeneratorImpl.java:295)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.freeId(CommonAbstractStore.java:404)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doRollback(WriteTransaction.java:309)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.rollback(XaTransaction.java:278)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.rollback(XaResourceManager.java:488)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.rollback(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:111)
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState.rollback(TransactionState.java:193)
        at com.sun.jts.jtsxa.OTSResourceImpl.rollback(OTSResourceImpl.java:333)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.RegisteredResources.distributeRollback(RegisteredResources.java:1038)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.rollback(TopCoordinator.java:2290)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorTerm.commit(CoordinatorTerm.java:420)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TerminatorImpl.commit(TerminatorImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentImpl.commit(CurrentImpl.java:623)
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:186)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:858)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:208)
............
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:299)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.IdGeneratorImpl.writeIdBatch(IdGeneratorImpl.java:530)
        ... 104 more
```

What can i do, and how can i recover from that exception ?

I must say neo4j is here run using neo4j jca connector in a Glassfish app server.

So. What can i do ?

Comment: you are probably using several threads where one tries to write to a section which has been already deleted by an other thread. what does your code exactly do before this happens?

Comment: @ulkas This code is run in a Singleton Startup EJB that migrates a bunch of data in the graph. It is supposed to be the only EJB running at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in fact not related to neo4j, but rather to the fact that Glassfish gives as default a limited time for EAR to deploy (not directly, but through the HTTP channel used to send the command to the domain).

A hint of that was given in the form of that mysterious log statement :

> [#|2012-12-10T11:41:49.725+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: admin-thread-pool-4848(9).|#]

A quick googling told me exactly what happened to my EAR deployment : "[application cannot start on ubuntu but starts on windows without any trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150624/application-cannot-start-on-ubuntu-but-starts-on-windows-without-any-trouble)". As a consequence I followed java.net advice and set the given flag

```
asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.request-timeout-seconds=-1
```

Error has now disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff in java.nio.* is very sensitive to interrupts, which means that a FileChannel closes as soon as a thread that has been interrupted accesses it. Neo4j uses FileChannel and this problem is most likely caused by your environment interrupting threads one way or another.